# IntellIJ не компилируется

Tags: java, intellij-idea, компилятор, драйвер, nvidia

[image: Вот такая ошибка выскакивает как только начинаю компиляцию]

Но если полностью удалить драйвер видеокарты - то проблема исчезает. Но без драйвера я не могу. Видяха: нвидиа 540М.
Может кто сталкивался? Как быть? Версии Java и IntellIJ актуальны.

Answer (score 1):

На эту тему был заведен в [тикет](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206640459-Abnormal-build-process-termination) для `Intellij Idea`. Это связано с драйвером `nvidia`. Советуют откатиться до версии 368.81.

Answer (score 1):

Весь день копался, искал причину. Как и следовало ожидать, это через драйвер nvidia geforce. Сперва поставил версию драйвера 368.81, но проблема осталась.
Ошибку решил доволи-таки просто:

1. Поставил самый актуальный драйвер(378.49)
2. Удалил этот же драйвер через деинсталлятор программ в windows
3. На его место автоматически(без моего ведома) через некоторое время винда
   поставила драйвер ранней версии(но теперь он не отображается в
   списке программ)(версия драйвера - 376.19)
4. Запустил IDE - всё
   работает.

Правда как теперь обновлять до актуальной версии этот драйвер при необходимости - не знаю.
Мои параметры: windows 10; geforce 540M